# Problems inserting null into integer fields in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following error that fails when building a dynamic insert query with a nullable integer:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(
    [my_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [so_id] [int] NULL
)

CREATE TABLE TestTable2(
    [my_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [so_id] [int] NULL
)


DECLARE @so_id AS   int;
DECLARE @my_id  AS INT;
declare @my_sql as nvarchar(max);

INSERT INTO TestTable (my_id, so_id)  VALUES (1, NULL); --so_id might be null or 0,1,2

set @my_id = (SELECT top 1 my_id FROM TestTable);
SET @so_id = (SELECT top 1 so_id FROM TestTable);

SET @my_sql = 'INSERT INTO TestTable2 (my_id, so_id) VALUES (' + CAST(@my_id AS varchar(MAX)) +  ',  NULL )'    --if so_id is null insert null into TestTable2

EXEC sp_executesql @my_sql

SELECT * FROM TestTable2

SET @my_sql = 'INSERT INTO TestTable2 (my_id, so_id) VALUES (' + CAST(@my_id AS varchar(MAX)) +  ', ' + ISNULL(@so_id, 'NULL') + ')'    --if so_id is null insert null into TestTable2

EXEC sp_executesql @my_sql

DROP TABLE TestTable
DROP TABLE TestTable2
```

I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'INSERT INTO TestTable2 (my_id, so_id) VALUES (1, ' to data type int.

Comment: Problem is here:  `ISNULL(@so_id, 'NULL')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @my_sql = 'INSERT INTO TestTable2 (my_id, so_id) VALUES (' + CAST(@my_id AS varchar(MAX)) +  ', ' + ISNULL(CAST(@so_id AS VARCHAR), 'NULL') + ')'    --if so_id is null insert null into TestTable2
```

Comment: Always specify length for CAST. If we dont specify length, default length of 30 is taken, which can somtimes cause truncation

Comment: `DECLARE @sqlstmt VARCHAR(max)) = `SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountOfRows,'TableName' AS TableName FROM  TableName;';select cast(@sqlstmt as varchar)
SELECT LEN('SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountOfRows') `. It is truncated to 30 charactes

Answer (score 1):

Use parameters!

```
SET @so_id = (SELECT top 1 so_id FROM TestTable);

SET @my_sql = '
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (my_id, so_id)
    VALUES (@my_id,  NULL )';

EXEC sp_executesql @my_sql,
                   N'@my_id int',
                   @my_id = @my_id;
```

Of course dynamic SQL for this is silly, when you can do:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (my_id, so_id)
    SELECT TOP 1 so_id, NULL
    FROM TestTable;
```

And, it is unusual to use `SELECT TOP` without `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Eric, see, also, [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql).

Comment: This is a mock version of  that reproduces an error in some dynamic sql that I'm actually running.

Answer (score 0):

In the last sql statement you are attempting to insert `'NULL'` into an INT column. One solution would be to omit the null fields from the insert altogether as the values will be null when omitting during the insert.

```
SET @my_sql = 'INSERT INTO TestTable2 (my_id'
                +CASE WHEN @so_id IS NULL THEN ')' ELSE ',so_id) 'END
                +'  VALUES (' + CAST(@my_id AS varchar(MAX)) +  ''
                +CASE WHEN @so_id IS NULL THEN ')' ELSE ','+CAST(@so_id AS nvarchar(20))+') ' END
```